# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to test insert a row into sqlite3 db, for the Rails Tutorial in Chapter 7.  I have gone over the code many times and it looks correct, however in the console I am getting the following error.  Any suggestions?

> > User.create(name=>"test user",:email=>"testuser@example.com",:password=>"foobar",:password_confirmation=>"foobar")
> >     ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in `maximum'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in`**send**'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:442:in `maximum'
> >         from /Users/gabemcmillan/rails_projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:10
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in`load'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load_file'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in`new_constants_in'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in`require_or_load'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in `load_missing_constant'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in`const_missing'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`const_missing'
> >         from (irb):8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `User.create(:name...` (with a colon before `name`), not `User.create(name...`